# Print CSS for large table

Tags: css, printing

I have a rather large table, that is separated out into smaller sections with spacer rows

```
<table>
<tr><th>Heading</th>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr class='spacer_row'><td></td></tr>
<tr><th>Heading</th>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr class='spacer_row'><td></td></tr>
<tr><th>Heading</th>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
<tr class='spacer_row'><td></td></tr>
.........
.........
</table>
```

I am creating a print.css, I would like to force page breaks at `spacer_row` if needed.
How do i use the page-break css properties?

Comment: Update: Gave up after experimenting a bit. Support of print css varies among browsers. More importantly, the browsers do not seem to allow conditional positioning of page breaks *within* a single table, so I think I have to write new markup with each section being a separate table

Answer (score 1):

This css rule will ensure a new page will start after each spacer row:

```
.spacer_row
{
   page-break-after: always;
}
```

See [`page-break-after`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-after).

Comment: I don't want it `always`, only if needed it be placed at `spacer_row`

Comment: @RisingSun - Then only place it on those rows. You can create a special CSS class for those rows and add it to them.

Comment: The table is being generated from a database, I wouldn't be *knowing* where the page breaks will be. 3 - 5 sections would easily fit on a page

Comment: @RisingSun - You won't know until you print. **You** need to decide where to put the page breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, although I have not tested it myself.  I had good results on pages using it on div, p and other tags.  Might work:

**CSS** (tell the browser to avoid having a page break within a tbody tag)

```
tbody {page-break-inside:avoid}
```

**HTML** (Wrap each group of rows in a tbody tag and keep your spacer rows)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Heading</th>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr class='spacer_row'><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Heading</th>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr class='spacer_row'><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Heading</th>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>...</tr>
    <tr class='spacer_row'><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    .........
    .........
  </tbody>
</table>
```

That's a good starting test.

In production, I would avoid actually putting the page-break-inside:avoid css on all tbody tags, and instead create a css class that you can apply to tbody or any container tags.  Here's the reason: I have found a bug in IE (all the way up to IE8) where if you nest containers that have that CSS and IE is forced to page break inside, IE seems to truncate the rest of the page.

Unfortunately, this [w3schools.com page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp) says that the only browser that supports page-break-inside is opera.  Here's hoping for better support in the future